# Windows 7 - displaying a message if an event occurs

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler, event-viewer

I'd like to get a message when event 7026 occurs. (7026 = driver failed to load)
But I can't create a working task for this purpose.
Creating a task on the event (In Event Viewer right click on selected event, then Attach Task To This Event...) doesn't work.

Is there any way to do this with one task?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry... The task, which I've attached to this event has only a "Display a message" action. But these events occur during the boot procedure and - naturally - at boot time windows can't show the message box.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a batch file similar to the following run at startup:

```
@echo off
set evtid=7026
set timepd=30000
for /f %%a in ('wevtutil qe System /rd:true /f:text "/q:*[System[(EventID=%evtid%) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= %timepd%]]]" ^| find /c "%evtid%"') do set evtcnt=%%a
if %evtcnt% gtr 0 (
    echo WScript.Echo "Event %evtid% occurred %evtcnt% time(s) in the last " ^& ^(%timepd%/1000^) ^& " seconds!" > Msg.vbs
) else (
    echo WScript.Echo "Event %evtid% did not occur even once in the last " ^& ^(%timepd%/1000^) ^& " seconds!" > Msg.vbs
)
wscript Msg.vbs
del Msg.vbs
```

It uses the *wevtutil* command line utility to query the **System** event log for all instances of event 7026 in the last 30s.